# Delete all but {x} C# string

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to cycle through a .txt to build a test function for another application I'm building.

I've got a list of UK based lat/long values that are formatted like this:

```
Latitude: 57°39′55″N   57.665198
Longitude: 6°57′27″W   -6.95739395
Distance: 184.8338 mi  Bearing: 329.815°
```

with the intended result of this small application being just the lat/long values:

```
57.665198
-6.95739395
```

So far I've got a `StreamReader` working with a `myString.StartsWith("Latitude") {}` but I'm stuck.

How do I detect a splitstring of `2 spaces "  "` inside of a string and delete everything before that? My code so far is this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "";
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\mb\latlong.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            if (text.Trim().StartsWith("Latitude: "))
            {
                text.Split()
            } else if (text.StartsWith("Distance: "))
            {

            } else if (text.StartsWith(""))
            {

            }
            streamReader.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: a regex might be better.

Comment: I would suggest: Read the line and then parse it backwards. Read from the last char of the line until the first space occures.

Comment: @ckruczek ah that makes sense, I'll run through it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using *regular expressions*

```
  var result = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt") 
    .SelectMany(line => Regex
       .Matches(line, @"(?<=\s)-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$")
       .OfType<Match>()
       .Select(match => match.Value));
```

Test

```
  // 57.665198
  // -6.95739395
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.IndexOf("  ")` to find the position of the two spaces in the string.  Then you can use `string.Substring(position)` to get the string after that point.

In your code:

```
if (text.Trim().StartsWith("Latitude: "))
{
   var positionOfTwoSpaces = text.IndexOf("  ");
   var latString = text.Substring(positionOfTwoSpaces);
   var latValue = float.Parse(latString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the regular expression solution. (You might need to fix up the space counts in the regex definitions)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "";
    Regex lat = new Regex("Latitude: .+?   (.+)");
    Regex lon = new Regex("Longitude .+?   (.+)");
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\mb\latlong.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine() != null)
        {
           if (lat.IsMatch(line))
               lat.Match(line).Groups[1].Value // latitude

           else if(lon.IsMatch(line))
               lon.Match(line).Groups[1].Value // longitude
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be

```
string[] fileLines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("input file path");
List<string> resultLines = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in fileLines) {
    string[] parts = line.Split("  "); //Double space
    if (parts.Count() > 1) {
        string lastPart = parts.LastOrDefault();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastPart)) {
            resultLines.Add(lastPart);
        }
    }
}
IO.File.WriteAllLines("output file path", resultLines.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

As I already suggested in my comment. You can look for the last occurrence of the space and substring from there.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
   public static void Main()
   {
        String line = String.Empty;
        while(!String.IsNullOrEmpty((line = streamReader.ReadLine())))
        {
            if(line.StartsWith("Latitude:"))
            {
                line = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
```

Working [example](https://ideone.com/ZJ3ybv).
I didn't provide all the code because this is just copy paste for the longitude case. I think you can do this by your own. :)